# Are these element in a group algebra of a torsion-free group zero divisors?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, oa.operator-algebras, group-algebras, group-rings

Let $G$ be an arbitrary torsion-free group. For $x,y\in G$, which of these elements‌ can be decided immediately not to be zero divisors in $\mathbb ZG$ (or in $\mathbb CG$)?
$$1+x+y,\quad 4+x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1},\quad\text{or}\quad 3+x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1}$$

Comment: The second one cannot be a zero-divisor in $\mathbb CG$. This is a standard argument looking at the action of $\mathbb CG$ on $\ell^2(G)$. If some non-zero vector $\xi \in \ell^2(G)$ is annihilated by $4+x+x^{-1}+y+y^{-1}$ one can show using computations with scalar products that $-x\xi = \xi$. But that is impossible if $x$ has infinite order. For the other two, I do not think that it is known if they can be zero-divisors or not.

Comment: For any group $G$ and any fixed nonzero $w\in ZG$, an easy argument shows that $w$ is zero divisor in $ZG$ iff it's zero divisor in $CG$ (iff it's in $KG$ for $K$ of char 0). And this implies $w$ being zero divisor in $(Z/pZ)G$ for each prime $p$.

Comment: @YCor: I do not understand why if $w$ is zero divisor in $\mathbb CG$, it is also a zero divisor in $\mathbb ZG$?

Comment: Let me prove it for $1+x+y$, the general case is similar. If it's zero divisor in $KG$ ($K$ field of char 0 or more generally ring that's a torsion-free $Z$-module), it means that there's a nonzero finitely supported family $(r_g)_{g\in G}$ such that $r_g+r_{x^{-1}g}+r_{y^{-1}g}=0$ for all $g$. Let $A$ be the abelian subgroup generated by these elements, and choose a homomorphism $f:A\to Z$ not vanishing on all $r_g$. Then $f$ maps $(f(r_g))_{g\in G}$ is a family with the same property in $Z$ instead of $K$ (note that the product of $K$ does not appear!). So $1+x+y$ is zero divisor in $ZG$.

Comment: @AndreasThom: can you please explain why $-x\xi=\xi$ is impossible?

Comment: That's clear: $(-x\xi)=\xi$ implies $\xi(x^{2n}g)=\xi(g)$ for all $g$, and being $\ell^2$, it forces $\xi=0$.

Comment: Explanation on the the other part of Andreas' argument: it works for any sum of the form $r+\sum_{i=1}^nt_ig_i$ such that $\sum |t_i|=r$ and $g_i$, all $t_i$ are nonzero, and such that the subgroup $H$ generated by the $g_i$ is infinite. Indeed, if $-rv=\sum_{i=1}^nt_ig_iv$, using that we have equality in the triangle inequality implies that all $t_ig_iv$ and $-rv$ are positively collinear, and thus $t_ig_iv=-v$ for all $i$, so $Cv$ is $H$-invariant, so $v=0$. Actually, if $r>\sum|t_i|$, the argument works regardless of assuming $H$ infinite to show that $r+\sum t_ig_i$ is not zero divisor.

Comment: @YCor  Could you please give me a reference(or a proof)  for your claim: $ZG$ has no zero divisor then $CG$ has no zero divisor?

Comment: @AlirezaAbdollahi I haven't made this claim. I proved that each element of $ZG$ has no zero divisor, then no (nonzero) element of $ZG$ is zero divisor in $CG$.

Comment: It seems that if a zero-divisor $t$ is supported on a very small set and $st=0$ for some $s \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{C}[G]$, then $s$ has large support. For instance, with $t=1+x+y$, then the support of $s$ has at least 17 elements; see https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/etd/6932/